# Подключение нескольких контроллеров

Tags: веб-программирование, controller, angularjs

Пытался подключить несколько контроллеров. Делал следующим образом:

**hello1.js**

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('Hello1', [function($scope) {
  $scope.hello='Hello1';
}]);
```

**hello2.js**

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('Hello2', [function($scope) {
  $scope.hello='Hello2';
}]);
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Главная</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <script src="scripts/hello2.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller="Hello2">{{hello2}}</div>
    <script src="scripts/hello1.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller="Hello1">{{hello1}}</div>
</body>
```

</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас  `$scope` не определен, надо либо так:

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('Hello1', function($scope) {
  $scope.hello='Hello1';
}); //в этом случае перед минификацией приложения надо прогнать его через ngmin
```

либо так:

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('Hello1', ['$scope',function($scope) {
  $scope.hello='Hello1';
}]);
```

Также во втором скрипте не надо объявлять модуль (убрать [] из первой строки), иначе модуль будет переобъявлен.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4GuhBn84hNBDVV2ayx0h?p=preview

причем не нужно сами скрипты объявлять в теле, переместите их в хедер.

http://plnkr.co/edit/cug0cuUowxmkqlFMSCu7?p=preview

И да, забыл то, что написано во втором ответе тоже, переменная одинаково называется.

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.hello='Hello1';
$scope.hello='Hello2';
```

Имя переменной у вас какое?! В обоих случаях **hello**!

{{hello1}} и {{hello2}} - исправьте на {{**hello**}}